# SP13: Connecting Calendars

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, calendar, connection

I have 4 calendars that I have overlaid into one calendar.  I want to be able to add an event in the overlay calendar (call it Calendar #1).  Based on the information entered into Calendar #1 (i.e. including a drop-down list for the end-user to select which calendar designated calendar) the information will appear in that designated calendar.  So, all events should not appear in all 4 calendars.

The question is how would I approach this task?  Would I use a web part connection? 
Let me know if you need further information. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with a workflow. My suggestion would be to create a 5th calendar that is empty that the other four sit on top of. When someone adds an item to that 5th calendar, based on the values (dropdown) the workflow creates an item in the appropriate calendar and then deletes the item from the 5th calendar (so there isn't a residual duplicate).

Comment: Thanks for your response @Adoba I created the 5th calendar and have overlaid the 4 onto the fifth.  However, when I enter an entry into the 5 calendar the entry only appears on the calendar.  I want to enter the entry in the 5th calendar and the entry should appear on the 5th calendar and the designated calendar (ie calendar #2).  Would I still use a workflow for this?  Thanks

Comment: If you want it on both, just don't have the workflow delete the original entry on the 5th.